# Lift an operation in ErrIO to Action in shake

Tags: shake-build-system

I use shake but the operations I call are in an ErrIO and not in the IO monad. How can I lift such operations into the `Action` monad. I could `runErr` and get and `Either` value and then call `throwIO` or `liftIO` (depending on the result). Is this the recommended approach?

The code could be like:

```
runErr2action :: ErrIO a -> Action a
runErr2action op = liftIO $ do
    res <- runErr  op
    case res of
        Left msg -> throw msg
        Right a -> return a
```

Perhaps connected question: Why is there no instance of `MonadError` for `Action`?

Comment: Do you mean Action rather than Accum? If not, can you link to Accum?

Comment: Sorry, I was confusing Action with something I was reading on when I wrote the question. I fixed the question and added draft code.  Thank you for tyour attention!

Answer (score 0):

A Shake rule is expected to either succeed producing the result it promised, or fail. In most cases, anything that it calls producing a `Left` or failure value should be turned into an exception, using `throw`/`error` (or ideally variants in `IO` with `liftIO`, so the exception happens at a specific point not based on evaluation order). However, there are a few cases where a sub-action failing might not fail the rule, e.g.:

1. Perhaps you are running a test, and the test failing is a valid and correct output that you handle in some well defined manner, by recording the failure. In many cases such a failure would be detected at a higher level.
2. Perhaps you have two ways to build something, and the `Either` indicates the first way failed, so you should try the second method.

As to why there's no `MonadError` instance for `Action`, the main reason is that there are a few `MonadError` type classes, and Shake doesn't depend on any of the libraries providing them, so it would introduce an additional dependency. It also wouldn't offer any significant benefit over `error` or `liftIO . throwError`.